# How to sum value from list of dict and set it to new key

Tags: python

i got some problem here i hope someone in here can help me out from this problem

i have list of dict

```
user_data = [{'name':'SAL-001':'amount':1000},
{'name':'SAL-001':'amount':2000},
{'name':'SAL-002':'amount':1000},
{'name':'SAL-003':'amount':1000},
{'name':'SAL-003':'amount':1000},
{'name':'SAL-003':'amount':2000}]
```

i want to sum amount from that list of dict that have same id and place it in new key total_amount like this

```
output = [{'name':'SAL-001','amount':1000,'total_amount': 1000},
{'name':'SAL-001','amount':2000,'total_amount': 3000},
{'name':'SAL-002','amount':1000,'total_amount': 1000},
{'name':'SAL-003','amount':1000,'total_amount': 1000},
{'name':'SAL-003','amount':1000,'total_amount': 2000},
{'name':'SAL-003','amount':2000,'total_amount': 4000}]
```

how i can achieve that output ? anyone can help me with this ?

i appreciate any answer thank you

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to implement this feature” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  You have to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question]( https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow. Best of all, each tutorial will teach you a collection of related techniques, rather than merely solving the immediate problem.

Comment: @JoniMangku your list of `dict` is invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below Code is written considering data is sorted by name

```
user_data = [{'name':'SAL-001','amount':1000},
{'name':'SAL-001','amount':2000},
{'name':'SAL-002','amount':1000},
{'name':'SAL-003','amount':1000},
{'name':'SAL-003','amount':1000},
{'name':'SAL-003','amount':2000}]

# First total_amount is set to it's amount

user_data[0]['total_amount']=user_data[0]['amount']

for user in range(1,len(user_data)):

    #we check whether we need to add the amount to the total amount
    # if the name is same we add current amount to the previous total amount

    if user_data[user]['name']==user_data[user-1]['name']:
        user_data[user]['total_amount']=user_data[user-1]['total_amount']+user_data[user]['amount']

    #if the name is different we initialize total amount to the current amount

    else:
        user_data[user]['total_amount']=user_data[user]['amount']
print(user_data)
```

If there are any changes/modifications or if there is a better way to do this than please let me know